# Access claiming duplicate record with no unique fields updated with Update Recordset/Addnew

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to allow my client to add a bunch of dates in a row with the few fields copied. None of these fields are unique in the table but it keeps flagging them as duplicates records. When I got into the the table the new records are not added to the table despite there not being any duplicates.

This is the code (edited for silly mistakes)

```
Public Sub Create_Click()

    Dim rsEventDayGroup  As DAO.Recordset
    Dim NextDate As Date

    Set rsEventDayGroup = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * From tblEventDays")

    NextDate = Me!Start.Value
    While DateDiff("d", NextDate, Me!End.Value) >= 0
            rsEventDayGroup.AddNew
                rsEventDayGroup!Start.Value = NextDate
                rsEventDayGroup!EventID.Value = Forms!frmEvents.Controls!ID.Value
                rsEventDayGroup!DayType.Value = Me!DayType.Value
                rsEventDayGroup!Period.Value = Me!Period.Value
            rsEventDayGroup.Update
        NextDate = NextDate + 1
    Wend
    rsEventDayGroup.Close

    Set rsEventDayGroup = Nothing

End Sub
```

I'm trying to copy fields EventID, DayType, and Period and create records for each day someone inputs. tblEventDays has it's own unique ID, called just "ID" that is an autonumber. I suspect it's the code screwing up somewhere, but as it was working just yesterday and I haven't changed it, I'm not sure what it could be. When I go to debug it highlights "rsEventDayGroup.Update" I've also tried changing Select * from the table with no luck.

Comment: If code worked before and nothing has changed, possible corruption. Are you able to manually add this same data to table? Instead of recordset Update, could try Execute method.

Comment: _None of these fields are unique in the table_. But that is probably the case. Why would you allow a bunch of identical values/records exist in the table?

Comment: They are not unique, the only thing unique is the entry ID. They are all part of one project with many, many other fields.  I didn't want the client to have to manually duplicate information when they have to enter in so many other fields.

Comment: @mazoula: Not needed. `NextDate` is declared as _Date_.

Comment: _They are not unique_ ... but, still, that what Access sees. Did you follow the advice from @June7 to enter the values manually?